# NullInjectorError: No provider for Store! AUTH GUARD Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm trying to develop Auth guard with Angular 9 but when I try to implement it into component in browser console gives me ERROR:

> > ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(SampleModule)[AuthGuard -> Store -> Store -> Store ->
> >     Store]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!
> >     NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(SampleModule)[AuthGuard -> Store ->
> >     Store -> Store -> Store]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!
> >         at NullInjector.get (core.js:1050)
> >         at R3Injector.get (core.js:16521)
> >         at R3Injector.get (core.js:16521)
> >         at R3Injector.get (core.js:16521)
> >         at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:35539)
> >         at R3Injector.get (core.js:16521)
> >         at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:905)
> >         at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:915)
> >         at Object.AuthGuard_Factory [as factory] (auth.guard.ts:17)
> >         at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:16747)
> >         at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:793)
> >         at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:752)
> >         at zone-evergreen.js:854
> >         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:400)
> >         at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:40744)
> >         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
> >         at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
> >         at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:570)

Here is the Guard:

```
import {
  CanActivate,
  CanActivateChild,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router'
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store'
import { AppState } from '../auth.store/states/app.state'
import { AuthService } from '../auth.services/auth.services'
import { AuthActions } from '../auth.store/actions/auth.actions'

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  constructor(private store$: Store<AppState>,
              private authService: AuthService) {
  }
```

This is my Sample module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { SampleComponent } from './sample.component';
import { AuthGuard } from 'app/auth.app/auth.guards/auth.guard';

const routes = [
    {
        path     : 'sample',
        component: SampleComponent,
        canActivate : [AuthGuard]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SampleComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),

        TranslateModule,
    ],

    providers:[
        AuthGuard
    ],

    exports     : [
        SampleComponent
    ]
})

export class SampleModule
{
}
```

And this is my app module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import 'hammerjs';
import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';
import { LayoutModule } from 'app/layout/layout.module';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path        : '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./auth.app/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
    },    
    {
        path        : '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./main/sample/sample.module').then(m => m.SampleModule)
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports     : [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),

        TranslateModule.forRoot(),

        // Material moment date module
        MatMomentDateModule,

        // Material
        MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule,

        // App modules
        LayoutModule,
        // SampleModule,
    ],
    bootstrap   : [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

Comment: Start by implementing the ngrx store properly: https://ngrx.io/guide/store

Comment: Where is `StoreModule` imported?

Comment: @unitario in my AuthModule

Comment: I move my StoreModule to app.module and it's ok now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add the store to the imports:

```
imports: [
 StoreModule.forRoot(...)
]
```

Comment: add to the imports where?